# Android list view with search functionality

Tags: android

My dynamic list view(populated from a webservice) has a AutoCompleteTextView, "Search" button.

I have implemented auto complete functionality for AutoCompleteTextView, it is working properly; when i type min 2chars, the AutoCompleteTextView is displaying matching results and when i select an item from the populated list, it is automatically appearing in the AutoCompleteTextView.

That is fine, now I need to implement action for my "Search" button, when I click on this button, the main list view should display the matched results only.

What is the best way to do it, without calling the webservice again?

Thanks in advance.
-nehatha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best Android way to do it is to use the [Quick Search Box](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html). Basically you implement a provider to return the search results in a cursor. That cursor will be used as the source to show a list of items. And you can customize the action to be done when the user clicks on the item.

Comment: Thank you. can you please provide resource with simple example with source code..

Comment: See the SearchableDictionary sample source code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution with the click event and going to the detail display

```
public class GinActivityList extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;
    private EditText et;
    private ArrayList<Object> array_sort = new ArrayList<Object>();
    int textlength = 0;
    private Object[] ginsArray;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ginsArray = (Object[]) General.GINS.values().toArray();
       setContentView(R.layout.list_search);

       lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
       et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

       lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ginsArray));

       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

               Gin ginSelected = (Gin) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);

               Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), GinActivityDetail.class);
               GinActivityGroup parentActivity = (GinActivityGroup) getParent();

               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putSerializable("ID_GIN", ginSelected.getId());
               intent.putExtras(bundle);

               parentActivity.startChildActivity("GinActivityDetail", intent);
           }
       });

       et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            textlength = et.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < ginsArray.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= ((Gin) ginsArray[i]).getName().length()) {
                    if (et.getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) ((Gin) ginsArray[i]).getName()
                                            .subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                        array_sort.add((Gin) ginsArray[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(GinActivityList.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}

 }
```

list_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Buscar" >
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</ListView>
```