# Search Functionality for Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-button

i'm new to android. I'm just trying to make one simple search functionality for my app. My app consists one `ListView` one `EditText` and one `Button` for search. My `ListView` contents are listed from database using custom adapter which is extends `BaseAdapter`

Now, what i'm trying to do is, i want to search any records from `ListView` For example, if i've some records like

> Optimization, Operations, Data Mining, Computer Ethics, Computer Architecture and etc...

So, when i type some record name like `op`

The listview should listed the records which is started from `op...` I've referred something for this, from i got [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) But, i don't know how to do this?

And, Can we do this same functionality with click of `button`

Has anyone having any idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/11009026/1398150

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220551/android-list-view-with-search-functionality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had asked a similar kinda question a while back. Here: [Filtering a ListView with Baseadapter  filters text not images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10764675/450534). Although, my specific question concerned a GridView, the concept (and the code) can be substituted for a ListView.

NOTE: This will be a lengthy post but I think necessary for the sake of completeness (I am leaving out the `imports` though)

The main activity (*Friends.java*)

```
public class Friends extends SherlockActivity {

    // BUNDLE OBJECT TO GET DATA FROM EARLIER ACTIVITY
    Bundle extras;

    // INITIAL ALBUM ID AND NAME
    String initialUserID;

    // THE GRIDVIEW
    GridView gridOfFriends;

    // THE ADAPTER
    FriendsAdapter adapter;

    // ARRAYLIST TO HOLD DATA
    ArrayList<getFriends> arrFriends;

    // LINEARLAYOUT TO SHOW THE FOOTER PROGRESS BAR
    LinearLayout linlaProgressBar;

    // THE EDITTEXT TO FILTER USERS
    EditText filterText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.friends_grid_list);

        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras.containsKey("USER_ID"))  {
            initialUserID = extras.getString("USER_ID");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(), 
                    "There was a problem getting your Friends Data. Please hit the back button and try again.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Your Friends");

        // CAST THE GRIDVIEW
        gridOfFriends = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridFriends);

        // INSTANTIATE THE ARRAYLIST
        arrFriends = new ArrayList<getFriends>();

        // CAST THE ADAPTER
        adapter = new FriendsAdapter(Friends.this, arrFriends);

        // CAST THE LINEARLAYOUT THAT HOLDS THE PROGRESS BAR
        linlaProgressBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaProgressBar);
        linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // GET THE LOGGED IN USERS FRIENDS DATA
        if (initialUserID != null)  {
            new getFriendsData().execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(), 
                    "There was a problem getting your Friends Data. Please hit the back button and try again.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // CAST THE EDITTEXT AND SETUP FILTERING
        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFilterList);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }

    private class getFriendsData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            // SHOW THE BOTTOM PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) WHILE LOADING THE FRIENDS LIST
            linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                String query = 
                        "SELECT name, uid, pic_big " +
                        "FROM user " +
                        "WHERE uid in " +
                        "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) " +
                        "order by name";
                Bundle paramGetFriendsList = new Bundle();
                paramGetFriendsList.putString("method", "fql.query");
                paramGetFriendsList.putString("query", query);

                String resultFriendsList = Utility.mFacebook.request(paramGetFriendsList);

                JSONArray JAFriends = new JSONArray(resultFriendsList);

                getFriends friends;

                if (JAFriends.length() == 0)    {

                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < JAFriends.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject JOFriends = JAFriends.getJSONObject(i);

                        friends = new getFriends();

                        // SET FRIENDS ID
                        if (JOFriends.has("uid"))   {
                            friends.setFriendID(JOFriends.getString("uid"));
                        } else {
                            friends.setFriendID(null);
                        }

                        // SET FRIENDS NAME
                        if (JOFriends.has("name"))  {
                            friends.setFriendName(JOFriends.getString("name"));
                        } else {
                            friends.setFriendName(null);
                        }

                        // SET FRIENDS PROFILE PICTURE
                        if (JOFriends.has("pic_big"))   {
                            friends.setFriendProfile(JOFriends.getString("pic_big"));
                        } else {
                            friends.setFriendProfile(null);
                        }

                        arrFriends.add(friends);

                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // SET THE ADAPTER TO THE GRIDVIEW
            gridOfFriends.setAdapter(adapter);

            // HIDE THE BOTTOM PROGRESS BAR (SPINNER) AFTER LOADING THE FRIENDS LIST
            linlaProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

The *getFriends.java* class for the `ArrayList`:

```
public class getFriends {

    String friendID;
    String friendName;
    String friendProfile;

    // SET FRIENDS ID
    public void setFriendID(String friendID) {
        this.friendID = friendID;
    }

    // GET FRIENDS ID
    public String getFriendID() {
        return friendID;
    }

    // SET FRIENDS NAME
    public void setFriendName(String friendName) {
        this.friendName = friendName;
    }

    // GET FRIENDS NAME
    public String getFriendName() {
        return friendName;
    }

    // SET FRIENDS PROFILE
    public void setFriendProfile(String friendProfile) {
        this.friendProfile = friendProfile;
    }

    // GET FRIENDS PROFILE
    public String getFriendProfile() {
        return friendProfile;
    }
}
```

And finally, the adapter class (*FriendsAdapter.java*)

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    Activity activity;

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    ArrayList<getFriends> arrayFriends;
    List<getFriends> mOriginalNames;

    FriendsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<getFriends> arrFriends) {

        activity = a;

        arrayFriends = arrFriends;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayFriends.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayFriends.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_grid_items, null);

        ImageView imgProfilePicture = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture);
        TextView txtUserName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        FrameLayout mainContainer = (FrameLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);


        txtUserName.setText(arrayFriends.get(position).getFriendName());

        if (arrayFriends.get(position).getFriendProfile() != null) {
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrayFriends.get(position).getFriendProfile(),imgProfilePicture);
        } else if (arrayFriends.get(position).getFriendProfile() == null) {
            imgProfilePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mainContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent showFriendsProfile = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), UserProfileNew.class);
                showFriendsProfile.putExtra("USER_ID", arrayFriends.get(position).getFriendID());
                showFriendsProfile.putExtra("NAME", arrayFriends.get(position).getFriendName());
                activity.startActivity(showFriendsProfile);
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {

                arrayFriends = (ArrayList<getFriends>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<getFriends> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<getFriends>();

                if (mOriginalNames == null) {
                    mOriginalNames = new ArrayList<getFriends>(arrayFriends);
                }
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = mOriginalNames.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalNames;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalNames.size(); i++) {
                        getFriends dataNames = mOriginalNames.get(i);
                        if (dataNames.getFriendName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                        }
                    }

                    results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                    // System.out.println(results.count);

                    results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                    // Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());
                }

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

You can use the concept here and substitute for your ListView. I have used this elsewhere for a ListView and works as it should. Unfortunately, I cannot give that code away on a public fora. Hope this helps you though. Again, a very lengthy post no doubt, but necessary I believe.

Comment: @Newbie_to_Android: try substituting bits from the code above in your getFilter() method. You may have to make a few changes to your code to accommodate the concept from my code though. For instance, you will another List (check the mOriginalName List<>) to hold the data filtered and then call notifyDataSetChanged() to display in your list.

Comment: I am using a custom class called getFriends for my ArrayList. Like I said, you will have to make a few substitutions. Can you add your main activity code to the post? I think that will make it easier.

Comment: In the getFilter() method, try substituting the getFriends with "String"

Comment: Yes, its working fine. But, if i search anything with letter of `a` it will the items which is contains letter `a` Can't we do this for these letter matches only starting letters?

Comment: In this block, change the ".contains" to ".equalsIgnoreCase"       `if (dataNames.getFriendName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
       FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
      }`

Comment: And I'm glad to have helped. ;-)

Comment: I'm also happy that i can handle the `Filterable` interface by your guide. Thank you. And, one more thing, `.equlsIgnoreCase` is not working. It will not display anything if the string is there also. But, i'm happy with `.contains` its enough for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Newbie_to_Android: You are right. `.equalsIgnoreCase` will not work. It will match the complete word and find as per the text typed. Not practical at all actually.

Comment: May i ask one doubt here? I'm facing one issue with this?

Comment: I'm also having these same functionality. But, i've contains data like `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` I tried with your code. Its not working for me. What i'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: @SpK: I am not sure how to handle the filtering with `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. Perhaps, you could try posting a new question.

Comment: See if the tutorial on this site works for you. Did a quick Google and got this way down the page: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: Here you are searching for getFriendName() but how to search for all object.

Comment: @Kartheek: I am not sure I understand what you mean by _all object_?

Answer (score 1):

check this [`List View with easy searching in Android`](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)

Comment: This is what i'm searching for. Thank you lot. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

you may use Auto completer with your Editext and using that update your List Adapter and  Also  [see](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html)

```
<yourEditText>.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            <requery/filter your adapter then set it to your listview>
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```