# Swift this code is working in android how would i do in swift Multiple autocomplete in textview

Tags: swift, autocomplete

With Swift, I have a problem in multiple autocomplete in textview. I have found one link: how to create this in Swift 
[Android: Autocomplete TextView Similar To The Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691679/android-autocomplete-textview-similar-to-the-facebook-app)?