# MultiAutoCompleteTextView with Custom Adapter displays garbled string

Tags: android, baseadapter

This is a follow up to my question earlier here: [Android: Autocomplete TextView Similar To The Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12691679/1350013).

*The Background:*

My requirement in the question (link posted above) was to have an `AutoCompleteTextView` similar to the one used in the Facebook app and several others too. The solution was to use a multi-line `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` The idea was to enable users to type their Friends names directly while creating a Status Update. The solution in the answer works fine from a standalone point of view. However, when I stared integrating the solution in my existing code, it still works with the correct drop-down et all. I see the filtered list of my friends thanks to a solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12363961/1350013. I use a custom `ListView` with a `BaseAdapter` instead of the `GridView` from the solution.

*The Problem:*

My code makes use of a `BaseAdapter` which implements `Filterable`. As mentioned above, works fine.

When I select a Friend from the filtered list, is where the problem is. The `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, after selection, displays this: **`@MY_PACKAGE_NAME.Friends.getFriends@406c1058`** instead of the Friend's name. What would I have to change to show the Name instead of the garbled text? If it helps, the Class I run this in extends a `SherlockActivity` and not a `SherlockListActivity`.

Now I am not sure what the relevant code would be to find out where the problem might lie, so I will post as much relevant code as possible. I am a noob, so please be easy and ask for any additional code. I will promptly comply. Likewise, if something here is not needed is cluttering the post, I will remove that.

*CODE BLOCKS*

*The Tokenizer* from the solution from my earlier question. Linked at the top (In the `onCreate()` method)

```
editStatusUpdate = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editStatusUpdate);
editStatusUpdate.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

editStatusUpdate.setTokenizer(new Tokenizer() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {

        int i = text.length();

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            i--;
        }

        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(), Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return text.toString() + " ";
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {

        int i = cursor;

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
            i--;
        }

        if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
            return cursor;
        }

        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {

        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();

        while (i < len) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                return i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return len;

    }
});
```

The TextWatcher, also from the solution to the earlier question:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        Layout layout = editStatusUpdate.getLayout();
        int pos = editStatusUpdate.getSelectionStart();
        int line = layout.getLineForOffset(pos);
        int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line);

        int bottom = editStatusUpdate.getHeight();

        editStatusUpdate.setDropDownVerticalOffset(baseline - bottom);

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

For my ArrayList:

```
public class getFriends {

    String friendID;
    String friendName;
    String friendProfile;

    boolean selected;

    // SET FRIENDS ID
    public void setFriendID(String friendID) {
        this.friendID = friendID;
    }

    // GET FRIENDS ID
    public String getFriendID() {
        return friendID;
    }

    // SET FRIENDS NAME
    public void setFriendName(String friendName) {
        this.friendName = friendName;
    }

    // GET FRIENDS NAME
    public String getFriendName() {
        return friendName;
    }

    // SET FRIENDS PROFILE
    public void setFriendProfile(String friendProfile) {
        this.friendProfile = friendProfile;
    }

    // GET FRIENDS PROFILE
    public String getFriendProfile() {
        return friendProfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked through the other question's code but it seems that the method `toString` is getting called for your `getFriends` class(horrible naming by the way). Try to add an overrided `toString` method to the `getFriends` class, something like this: `@Override public String toString() {return friendName;}` and see what happens.

Comment: First. The solution in the comment worked right away. So please add this as an answer and I will accept it (with the set bounty) :-). Second. What would be a better way to name the class? When you say horrible, does it raise any concerns for the app malfunctioning? Or is it just bad naming practice?

Comment: I've exaggerated using "horrible", there is no problem with the app functioning properly it's just that you should use the java conventions(capital letter for class name). Also, maybe the `getFriends` isn't such a good option, for example when I first read your question `getFriends` seemed more like a method name and not a class. As your class it's a data holder a name like `FriendData` or `FriendInformation` might have been a more expressive name for someone reading your code. This isn't something crucial but if you have other persons reading it you would help them understand the code.

Comment: @Luksprog: Thanks for the tip.  Almost all similar classes in my app have these names and I will change them immediately. And again, thanks for the solution and the tip too. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the output you get it appears that your code calls the `toString` method on your `getClass` objects to retrieve the data it needs. As you want the friend's name you should implement your own `toString` method(by overriding it) like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return friendName; 
}
```

Comment: This is not how it should be done (and I would even say that it is wrong), there are designated methods for this conversion. You should not rely on the functions toString method.

Answer (score 14):

You should override `convertResultToString(Object resultValue)` in your filter, where Object is your class. This makes it possible to create a custom string for you class without relying on overriding the to String method.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. It works better with internationalisation as you dont need to get the application context in your model object.