# Searchable Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, listactivity, simpleadapter

Here I am Creating ListView which shows songlist. And on list item click i am passing the position of the song to play it. Means i have functionlke playSong(Int Index). That works perfactly. But when i perform search ,it shows searchable item and on that item click it i am not gettig the real position of it.

example :

list shows me items like 1) Be with You 2) Can you here me 3) let it be

but now when i search "can you here me" , it shows list with "can you here me". And when i click on this item , It takes 0 index and plays "Be with You" song.

so what is missing in my code ?? Please suggest me.

Here is my code :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null , null, null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE );          
          if (cursor == null) 
          {
              //Query Failed , Handle error.
          }
          else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) 
          {
             //No media on the device.
          }
          else
          {

              int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
              int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
              int artistcolumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
              int durationcolumn =cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);

              for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
              {
                    String thisTitle = cursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String path = cursor.getString(idColumn);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(artistcolumn);
                    Long duration = cursor.getLong(durationcolumn);
                    Utilities objUtilities = new Utilities();
                    String timeDuration = objUtilities.milliSecondsToTimer(duration);

                   HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   song.put("songTitle",thisTitle);
                   song.put("songPath", path);
                   song.put("artist", artist);
                   song.put("duration",timeDuration);

                   // Adding each song to SongList
                   songsList.add(song);
                   cursor.moveToNext();
              }
          }


        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }


        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        String[] from = {"songTitle", "artist" , "duration"};
        int[] to={R.id.songTitle,R.id.songArtist, R.id.duration};
         adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, from, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);

                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);                
                startActivity(in);  

            }
        });

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
            ((SimpleAdapter)getListAdapter()).getFilter().filter(cs);   

            }


            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Check this answer I had posted a sometime back ON SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12363961/450534. It has a complete solution including the adapter and the main activity for filtering (searching). It is for a `GridView`. But the concept is interchangeable.

Comment: @SiddharthLele  Sorry...but I am not getting idea from that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is override the `getItemId` method of your adapter to return the 'real' song index. Then you will retrieve this index from the `id` parameter of your `onItemClick` callback.

Try this:

```
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData, R.layout.playlist_item, from, to) {
        public long getItemId(int position) { 
            return songsListData.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }
    };
```

And make sure that your `songsListData` is declared final (so that you can access it from inside the adapter):

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Then in your `onItemClick` method just use `id` instead of `position`:

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting listitem index
            int songIndex = id;
            ...
```

Comment: @fiddler, can you help me in this case...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606766/search-item-in-edittext-from-listview-showing-wrong-result